# Error in Nginx config installing with sudo bash script with php

Tags: php, bash, shell, nginx

Installing Script using sudo bash using PHP Version 7.0.23-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 generating error. this is the Nginx Config file.

```
 #CREATING NGINX CONFIG FILES FOR EXAMPLE.COM
            tee /etc/nginx/sites-available/$example_com << EOF
    server {
            listen   80;


            root /var/www/$example_com;
            index index.php index.html index.htm;

            server_name $example_com;

            location / {
                    try_files \$uri \$uri/ /index.php?q=\$uri&\$args;
            }

            error_page 404 /404.html;

            error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
                  root /usr/share/nginx/www;
            }

            # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
            location ~ \.php\$ {
                    try_files \$uri =404;
                    #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                    # With php7.0-fpm:
                    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
                    fastcgi_index index.php;
                    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                    include fastcgi_params;
                     }
       }
    EOF
            ln -sF /etc/nginx/sites-available/$example_com /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/$example_com
            rm -rf /etc/nginx/sites-available/default &>> /dev/null
            service nginx restart >> $TEMP 2>&1
            if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
                    ee_info "Nginx is successfull installed"
            else
                    ee_fail "ERROR! Use:>>>sudo nginx -t<<<< in Terminal"
            fi
            service php7.0-fpm restart >> $TEMP 2>&1
            ee_fail "The above is your config file."
```

Generating this Error while running full script on server.

```
root@ubuntu-xenial:/home/ubuntu# nginx -t
nginx: [emerg] invalid number of arguments in "fastcgi_param" directive in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/test1.com:28
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

Please help me resolving this issue.

Comment: Seems error is in fastcgi_param file. Please show this file's content.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is this statement

```
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
```

You didn't escape the `$` for this

```
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME \$document_root\$fastcgi_script_name;
```